# How much power does the Martian heat ray output?

Tags: physics, war-of-the-worlds

In the influential H. G. Wells story, *The War of the Worlds*, the Martian fighting machine has a heat ray capable of projecting intense heat against anything it is turned on. I think the most impressive feat we see it perform is melting a hole in the ironclad *Thunderchild*. You'd think the water would provide an effective heat-sink, making the ship harder to melt.

About **how much power output did it take** to perform this feat in the (presumably) few seconds it took?

The book doesn't say explicitly, but can we work it out from the information available? (I'm not counting the films because they have completely different plots to the book and don't share any authorship.)

Comment: If you re-word this to ask how much power **the book** (or the films) describe the ray as having, it would be on-topic.

Comment: @Richard The book doesn't say explicitly. The question is, can we work it out from the information available? I'm not counting the films because they have completely different plots to the book and don't share any authorship.

Comment: The problem is that you're looking for a real-world scientific explanation for something that happens in a fictional work. We could (theoretically) work it out using real-world science, but that's off-topic here.

Comment: @Richard I find it a bit odd that the canned reason you chose has a specific exception for questions that "relate directly to a cited work of fiction". Perhaps you didn't read the reason before choosing it?

Comment: The wording could be clearer. It allows science questions where the driver is the fiction. In this case you're basically asking "what output would a heat ray need to melt metal" with the fictional basis being largely irrelevant

Comment: This question belongs on physics.stackexchange.com, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56633/how-much-energy-would-it-take-to-blow-up-the-earth

Comment: I'm reopening this question because according to [our policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7367/31394), "in-universe explanations - even based on real science - are on-topic".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I think you've misunderstood the policy. That question was given as an exemplar of the sort of question that we **don't** want on the site.

Comment: Meta question - [Why has this science-based question been reopened?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/why-has-this-science-based-question-been-reopened).